# How to get value from wp_usermeta table in database?

Tags: customization, user-registration, table

I ad a custom field to registration form:

```
function wooc_extra_register_fields() {
<p class="form-row form-row-first">
<label for="billing_cpf"><?php _e( 'CPF', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_cpf" id="billing_cpf" placeholder="Somente número" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_cpf'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_cpf'] ); ?>" />
</p>
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );
```

And save:

```
function wooc_save_extra_register_fields( $customer_id) {
if ( isset( $_POST['billing_cpf'] ) ) {
    update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_cpf', $_POST['billing_cpf'] );
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wooc_save_extra_register_fields' );
```

I see that registtration custom fields are saved into table **wp_usermeta**. I need to check if **$_POST['billing_cpf']** already exist into this table and deny saving.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would take a look at the `get_user_meta` function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `add_user_meta` instead of `update_user_meta`:

```
if (isset($_POST['billing_cpf'])) {
    add_user_meta($customer_id, 'billing_cpf', $POST['billing_cpf'], true);
}
```

As this will **only** add the meta if it *does not already exist* - no update.

(This will prevent this field from being updatable - unless by you another way.)

Note: normally you could use something like this to add and update in combo so that the field **is** updatable:

```
if (isset($_POST['billing_cpf'])) {
    if (!add_user_meta($customer_id, 'billing_cpf', $POST['billing_cpf'], true)) {
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'billing_cpf', $POST['billing_cpf']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is still saving repeated values.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the 4th parameter (`$unique`) for add_user_meta. see edit.

Answer (score 1):

I read Codex document about `get_user_meta`... maybe it works. I made a test with the following code:

```
<?php 
$user_last = get_user_meta( 51, 'billing_cpf', true );
echo '<p>The '. $key . ' value for user id ' . $user_id . ' is: ' . $user_last . '</p>'; 
?>
```

Someone nows how to get all values saved for all users?  ($key = 'billing_cpf')